# Using gparted to resize ubuntu partition

Tags: gparted

I have unallocated space **before** the partition I'd like to extend? Gparted wont allow me to resize or move that partition (ext4)

my drive looks like this:

/dev/sdb1 (locked) fat32 
unallocated unallocated 
/dev/sdb2 (locked) ext4 mount point / 
/dev/sdb3 linux-swap

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cant extend the partition, you have booted Ubuntu from. This is the reason, why it is locked.

<del>Additionally you have to move the Partition `/dev/sdb2` so that the unused space is behind of it.</del>*

Booting from your Ubuntu disk will solve the Problem of the locked device. GParted is contained in the Ubuntu disk/stick.

EDIT: *
@Bytecommander told me, that you dont have to move the partition `/dev/sdb1`. However you still have to boot from a different OS like the Ubuntu Disc/Stick.

Comment: It is both possible to move either the left or the right border of the partition with gParted. It only has to be unmounted to move the left border. (Adding free space from right/behind the ext4 partition would also work when it's mounted, though)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I was able to add the space to the right of my ext4. But all the unallocated spacve (50gigs) is to the left of it, and that's the one I cannot add. Is there a way to add it without a gparted disk/stick? I cannot get my computer to boot from the gparted live I made with unebootin!!
It gets to the blue screen and then nothing happens...